# Как сделать 200 update ещё быстрее?

Tags: c#, sql-server

200 update в базе в несколько миллионов записей

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE T SET f1 = 1, f2 = 1, f3 = 1, f4 = 1 WHERE s='test1';
UPDATE T SET f1 = 1, f2 = 1, f3 = 1, f4 = 1 WHERE s='test2';
UPDATE T SET f1 = 1, f2 = 1, f3 = 1, f4 = 1 WHERE s='test3';
.....
UPDATE T SET f1 = 1, f2 = 1, f3 = 1, f4 = 1 WHERE s='test200';
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

на ssd у меня пишутся друг за другом минуту - быстрее можно? или менять базу чтобы писалось быстрее?

Answer (score 4):

1. использовать индекс.
2. сделать одним update.

Comment: @maxleo, насколько я понимаю, индекс вставку не ускорит, скорее наоборот, потому что при добавлении индекс надо перестраивать.

Почему может ускорить объединение апдейтов - тоже не понимаю. вроде все итак в рамках одной транзакции. Впрочем я не дба, могу ошибаться.

Comment: @Volt, вставку не усорит, но речь идет об обновлении - его ускорит существенно. а объединение в один запрос полезно, так как сервер работает с наборами записей - ему не придется обновлять две сотни наборов по одной записи (с вызовом соответствующих триггеров каждый раз, если они есть).

Comment: уточняю значения f1 f2 f3 f4 всегда разные для разных s
как в этом случае оптимизировать?

Comment: @maxleo, да, спасибо, туплю) Что-то приглючилось что речь про вставку =)

Comment: @prog432, сделать вложенный select с union, к нему по индексу приджойнить обновляемую таблицу - это если они известны сразу. если известны по очереди, то создать и заполнить временную таблицу, к которой приджойнить обновляемую.

Comment: Нет ли у Вас ограничений, каких-нибудь на Ваши f? Если имеются, то удалите их на время транзакции, а потом восстановите вновь. Конечно, если Вы уверены в том, что UPDATE не нарушает ограничений.

Comment: @prog432, CASE WHEN можно регулировать какие поля обновлять. Например f1=case when s='test' then 'Olololo' else f1 end. Это позволит сделать запрос на обновлением 1 апдейтом и в зависимости от s обновлять необходимые поля. Можно еще индексы на s поставить.